# Message passing in chrome extension not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, event-listener, message-passing

I'm new to chrome extensions and I'm having a bit of trouble getting started.

First of all my overall goal is to be able to click a button in my popup and have something in the DOM change. If I understand correctly, the way to do this is to load a content script and send this content script a message. This is what I have from looking at the Chrome developers page, but I don't see anything in the console log:

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Test",
    "version": "1.0",

    "permissions": [
        "tabs", "http://*/*"
    ],

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://*/*"],
            "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ],

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

popup.html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
            console.log(response.farewell);
        });
    });
});
```

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log(sender.tab ?
                    "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                    "from the extension");
        if (request.greeting == "hello")
            sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
    });
```

A lot of this code is directly from the docs, so I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I didn't see anything wrong with your code. What's your Chrome version? And according to your overall goal, I think you should probably listen to `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` (no popup) and programatically inject a content script (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi ) in the event handler.

Comment: @方觉 The message that I send to the content script depends on some user input in the popup, so I need it. My chrome version is Version 26.0.1410.63.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just copied your code onto my machine and ran it as-is and it works as you expect. I think you may be confused about *where* the `console.log` output you're expecting will appear, though.

Open any web page and open the console for that page. Click your browser action, the popup shows up, and sure enough the line `from a content script:chrome-extension://fndmlopghajebfadeabnfnfmhalelokm/popup.html` appears.

You don't see your `goodbye` line appear there, though – because that's being logged out from `popup.js`, not the tab's content script. Let's open an inspector for the popup and look for the `goodbye` message there. Right-click the browser action icon and select the "Inspect popup" menu item. Your (empty) popup shows, and a new inspector window appears; select the Console tab and you'll see the `goodbye` message there.

For additional info, see the [Chrome Extension Debugging tutorial](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging.html#inspect-popup).

*PS.* `chrome.tabs.getSelected` is deprecated; [you should use `chrome.tabs.query`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-query) instead. And I agree with 方 觉 – you ought to consider using programmatic injection to make your DOM changes instead.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. Is it possible to pass data to a script you programmatically inject? That's the reason I didn't do that, I didn't think it was possible to pass any data to the script.

Comment: @gsingh2011: per [the PI docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi), you could build an arbitrary string to send to `chrome.tabs.executeScript`. Or you could simply only insert your content script when needed, instead of on every page, via `chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content_script.js"});`. That would allow you to use the same architecture you've been planning on, without adding unnecessary scripts to every page the user ever opens.

Answer (score -1):

The popup.js script will launch the file when you load the popup.html (DOMContentLoaded). But surely, the content will be injected script is not yet in any web page, since you have not had time to not had time to open it and that "matches": ["http:// * / *"], is ok. Changes the background content script by background script and I think it will work.

Comment: I thought the content script was injected on page load, which is well before I open popup.html...