# how to get data from the background to be displayed in popup page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i want to display the array data i have in the background when the get data button is clicked but nothing is done when i click the button am very new for chrome ext. thanks.

manifest.json:

```
{
    "name":"modz",
    "manifest_version":2,
    "version":"1.0",
    "description":"this ext. will help you record all the urls you have visited",

    "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]

  },

    "browser_action":
    {
    "default_icon":"icon.png",
    "default_popup":"popup.html"
    },

    "permissions":[
          "tabs"
        ]

}
```

background.js:

```
var data=[];
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    var url = tab.url;
    if (url!=="undefined" && changeInfo.status=="complete")
  {
   data.push (tab.url);
   alert(data.length);
  }
  }

); 
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendrespose){
//send the array data back
});
```

popup.js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
   document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',function(){
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage("getdata");
   });
});
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\modz\Desktop\modz_extention\popup.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
     body{
       width:440px;
     }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<input  id="btn"  type="button"  value="get data" />
<div id="data"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Include a response function in [sendMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage) that does something with the data.  Then background.js calls `sendrespose(data)`.

Comment: could you please give me a code snippet as am very new to chrome ext and also the button dosent work could you please help me with that thank you

Comment: I would recommend [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16325442/2336725) or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16066317/2336725).

Comment: please post your previous comment as an answer as it was my answer so i could accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official reference for messaging is [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).  In your case, you’d want `background.js` to have

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponse){
    sendResponse({"dataArray":data});
});
```

`popup.js` would have

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',function(){
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({},function(response){
            document.getElementById("data").textContent = response.dataArray.toString();
        });
    });
});
```

This would also work in a content script.  But if the content script were running at the default `document_end`, it wouldn’t need the `DOMContentLoaded` event, since `document_end` happens afterward.

This is actually sending an empty message (the empty object `{}`).  If there were different messages you wanted to send, you’d want to change that.  This is also why `message` isn’t used in `background.js`.

Since you’re not really sending a message, another approach is to use [`getBackgroundPage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getBackgroundPage).  `background.js` wouldn’t need the listener, and `popup.js` would have:

```
chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(backgroundWindow){
    document.getElementById("data").textContent = backgroundWindow.data.toString();
});
```

Two more things:

- `popup.html` can’t use the absolute path to `popup.js`.  Put both in the extension directory, and use a relative path: `src="popup.js"`.
- Google recommends that you transition background pages to [event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages).  The biggest difference is that you can’t have the global variable `data` in event pages (you can, but it gets reset when the event page reloads).  If you have trouble getting that working, I’d recommend getting your extension working as a background page, and then posting another question.